# High-load payment processing architecture in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, architecture, payment, credit-card

Imagine a local Groupon clone. Now imagine a deal that attracted 10x normal visitors and because visitors were trying to buy deal in parallel MySQL database went down and deal's maximum purchases limit was exceeded.

I'm looking for best practices of the payment processing for highly-loaded websites, that will handle payments for the limited amount of products in parallel.

For now the simplest options seems to lock/unlock deal while customer is trying to purchase it on a third-party payment processor's page.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was with you until you started to talk about a 3rd party payment processors page.  It's hard to control your user's experience while dishing them off to a 3rd party site, because you have no idea what they're doing while they're there, if they got side-tracked, how long they're going to take to finish the transaction, IF they finished the transaction, etc.

If processing payments locally is not an option, that's not necessarily a problem - it just presents an issue with how you have to actually think about handling your transactions.

So, if it were me, not thinking about the 3rd party right now - we'll set that aside for a minute.  Obviously, I'd #1 make sure my MySQL database was resilient enough to not go down, because that creates a huge problem for reconciling transactions.  But, things happen, so you need a backup.

My suggestion would be to utilize a caching system which kept track of the product, and the current # of products available.  Memcache could be good for this, as it's just a single record which will be pretty easy to grab.  You wouldn't have to hit the database at all to get info on your product (availability) and if it went down, your users/application would be none the wiser, as you'd be getting info straight from Memcache about your item (no mysql required).

This presents an issue (when the database goes down) with storing payment records.  When you collect money, you obviously need that transaction information in your database, and if your database is down - well, that's a problem.  Memcache is not such a great solution for this, because you're limited to the size of your value and you must know about every key you care about.  On top of that, Memcache doesn't have sets or set operations, so you can't append to a value without fear of nuking some data.

So, lets add a different piece of technology, Redis.

A solution for the transaction problem would be to write them to redis in the event that your MySQL server is not available (or write to both if you really want to, but you don't really need to do that).  Then have a background process that knows how to go get the transaction details from redis and write them to your MySQL table(s) when it comes back online.  Redis is pretty resilient to crashing, and is capable of operating at huge volumes.  It also has set operations so you can easily append data to a set without fear of a race condition during your read/change/write operations.

So, you could store all your transactions in a redis key as a single set (store them as json strings if you like, that'd be pretty easy), then when your DB crashes you can just go get that data from Redis and write it to MySQL when it comes back online.

To keep things simple, if you were going use redis to store transactions, you may as well also  use it to store your product cache, instead of memcache - keep the stack simple.

This takes care of not accessing the database for your Product details, and also keeping track of your (potentially) missed transactions, should MySQL crash.  But it doesn't handle the problem of keeping track of product inventory while new transactions come in while MySQL is down, and ensuring that you don't over-sell product.

To handle this case, when a transaction is saved, you can decrement the # of products available (keep it as a flat number, so you're not constantly re-calculating it on page-load).  This will tell you instantly if the product is oversold or not.  However, what this does not do is protect the time that the "product is in the cart."  Once the user puts the product in the cart (which you've allowed because you said you have the inventory), you have the problem of making sure it doesn't sell out before they check out.

The solution to this problem also doubles as your solution to the 3rd party transaction problem.  So you're using a caching mechanism for your products, and a fall-back mechanism for your transactions.  What you should do now, is when a user tries to buy a product (either puts it in the carts, or is shot off to the 3rd party processor) create a "product reservation" for them.  It's probably easiest to make a redis entry for each of these.  Make product reservations have a expiry time, say 5 or 10, maybe even 15 minutes if you like.  Every time you see a user on your site, refresh the timeout to make sure they don't run out of time (you can put more logic in this if you desire, obviously).  When a transaction was completed and changed from pending to paid, you'd create your transaction record (mysql or redis, depending on database availability), decrement your available quantity, and delete your reservation record.

You'd then use your available quantity information, in addition to your un-expired reservation information, to determine the quantity available for sale.  If this number ever drops to zero, then you are effectively sold out; but if a certain number of your users don't convert it frees up the inventory that they didn't buy, allowing you to rinse and repeat that process until you're in fact, sold out.

This is a pretty long explanation of a fairly robust system, and if you ever run into the situation where your MySQL server crashed, AND redis crashed, you'd be kind of screwed; so it makes sense to have a failover of both of those systems here (which is entirely feasible and possible).  It should make for a pretty rock solid checkout/inventory management process.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your long explanation :) Sadly there is no way to handle payments on our side, and the problems like if transaction is finished and how's it going is totally manageable by payment API, that's not the problem.

In general your advice is helpful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use master slave mysql configuration with read/write connections.

Use cache as much as possible ([redis](http://redis.io/) is good idea).

Try to put some logic into redis, so it will not make extra connection to mysql + it will be faster.

For transactions maybe it is wise to use some kind of message queuing system ([rabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)). it will allow you to forward some tasks into background.

Dispate all this optimization you will have big problems if db or cache engine or mq will fail. But using master slave for all these services you will be kind of on the safe side. i.e. using multiple machines that will be able to continue to work if other machine fails.

And that brings me to next idea. cloud services with auto scaling (like [aws](http://aws.amazon.com/)).

Comment: I like the idea of using a message queue to pass messages to a background process, you could make an interesting infrastructure based on that. also, +1 for only connecting to the services you require when you need to

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was already thinking on message queue's and processing payments in the background process. I was also considering master/slave connections for database failover.

Answer (score 0):

Do you consider Compensating Service Transaction ?